# Add content to input in Flink and put the enrich content

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to use Flink, but I have some trouble, I keep the Flink example "WordCount" to explain my pain

I have 3 problems:

- how to get the counter in live streams for each word.
- how to enrich the input data.
- How to push all the enrich input on another socket.

Example:

```
______FirstInput_____
 | InputSocket_A : "hello word"
 | AfterWindowsCount : "hello:1 word:1"
 | AfterUniqCount : "hello:1 word:1 nbOfWord:2"
 | PutSocket_B: "hello:1 word:1 nbOfWord:2"

_____SecondeInput____
 | InputSocket_A : "hello word"
 | AfterWindowsCount : "hello:2 word:2"
 | AfterUniqCount : "hello:2 word:2 nbOfWord:2"
 | PutSocket_B: "hello:2 word:2 nbOfWord:2"
```

I am using the Scala API in Flink 1.3